# Legend symbol and text spacing problem in r studio

Tags: r, graph

I am using the code as given below

The problem is there is very long space between legend line and legend text as shown in figure. kindly help how i can reduce this spacing. such as spacing between legend numbers and lines like this

```
________          1

--------          2

legend(x=q-70, y=m, bty = "n", 
  legend = c("1","2","3", "4","5", "6","7", "8","9", "10","11", "12","13", "14","15", "16","17", "18","19", "20"), 
  lty = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4), 
  col = c("black", "red","green","blue","cyan","magenta","yellow","gray","black", "red","green","blue","cyan","magenta","yellow","gray","black", "red","green","blue"),  
  y.intersp=0.7, cex = 0.95,seg.len = 1.3, lwd = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this as-is. Can you make this question reproducible? That includes sample data (small) and the code to generate the plot as a whole.

Comment: I dnt know how to reproduce a good question, kindly see the legend code only and see the spacing between lines and numbers in the legend in the picture, please

Comment: Ditto.  I ran your legend code on a blank plot and did _not_ get any large gap between the line and the label.

Comment: Good references for how to produce good questions include: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: But in general, try it from our perspective: start with a fresh, empty R session. Take all of the code you have given us and try to run it. It's close, but it does not work because we do not have an existing plot to start from. If I lead with `plot(1)` then the call to `legend` works and does not error (which is good) but does not reproduce your issue here. I suggest you try to reproduce this problem with different types of data; best-case for a very reproducible question is using a well-known dataset included in R or one of its more popular packages.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you have explicitly set `y.intersp=0.7`.  I wonder if you have somehow set `x.intersp` as well.  At any rate,  if nothing else works for you, you could try various values of `x.intersp` until you get a position that you want. Here is a simple example on a blank background to show how `x.intersp` adjusts the position.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(0:2, pch="", xlab="", ylab="", bty="n", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", 
    main="x.intersp=1")
legend(x=1, y=2, bty = "n", 
  legend = c("1","2","3", "4","5","6","7","8","9","10",
    "11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"), 
  lty = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4), 
  col = c("black", "red","green","blue","cyan","magenta","yellow",
    "gray","black", "red","green","blue","cyan","magenta","yellow",
    "gray","black", "red","green","blue"),  
    x.intersp=1, y.intersp=0.7,  cex = 0.95,seg.len = 1.3, lwd = 2)

plot(0:2, pch="", xlab="", ylab="", bty="n", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", 
    main="x.intersp=4")
legend(x=1, y=2, bty = "n", 
  legend = c("1","2","3", "4","5","6","7","8","9","10",
    "11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"), 
  lty = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4), 
  col = c("black", "red","green","blue","cyan","magenta","yellow",
    "gray","black", "red","green","blue","cyan","magenta","yellow",
    "gray","black", "red","green","blue"),  
    x.intersp=4, y.intersp=0.7,  cex = 0.95,seg.len = 1.3, lwd = 2)
```

[image: Different Spacing]